# How make progress bar for audio-player?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an audio-player in python but I can't make it work with the progress bar with the song playing at the same time.
I don't know if I need make the clock or how implement the song in the progress bar.

````
def progress():
    if pb['value'] < 100:
        pb['value'] += 10
progress=ttk.Progressbar(window, orient=HORIZONTAL, cursor='hand2',
                         length=780,).place(x=95, y=500)```
````

I get the song of the listbox:

```
listBox=tk.Listbox(window, fg='cyan', bg='black', selectbackground='magenta', width=100, font=('ds-digital', 30))
listBox.place(x=80, y=6, width=550, height=370)
```

Screenshot of audio-player:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You haven't shown how you're playing the song, by you *may* be able to use the universal widget method [`after()`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html) to set up periodic calls to your `progress()` function to update the progressbar (which wouldn't require multithreading). See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72034488/355230) to another question for an example of using it.

Comment: ```listBox=tk.Listbox(window, fg='cyan', bg='black', selectbackground='magenta', width=100, font=('ds-digital', 30))
listBox.place(x=80, y=6, width=550, height=370)```

Comment: soorry XD but i get the song to the once listbox.... you were referring to that?

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. Once a song file has been selected, how is it being played so you can hear it? `tkinter` does not provide anyway of doing that itself.

Comment: @martineau ooook ok i undestand XD I get mp3 of the mutagen ```import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import random
import mutagen 
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import time
import threading

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Tejon's Bar player")
window.geometry("900x600")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.config(bg='black')   

style=ttk.Style()

rootpath="C:\\Users\\Victor\\Music\\mi musica"
Pattern="*mp3"

mixer.init()
```

Comment: Please put the code in your question. You need to provide a [mre] of the problem.