# Tkinter threading when to stop thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a `Tkinter` app. Two of the buttons in the UI code call other class functions. I start a thread for each of them like so:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.classOne.method_one())
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
```

And again for the second class method.

The second thread I start calls a resource intensive method and this freezes the app.

Is the reason it is freezing because I have not properly set up the threads? And should I be explicitly closing the threads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter locks python when Icon loaded and tk.mainloop in a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198262/tkinter-locks-python-when-icon-loaded-and-tk-mainloop-in-a-thread)

Comment: If you are accessing the Tkinter GUI objects from the second thread, then look at the duplicate question I linked to. If not, please include a small runnable example that shows the problem.

Comment: `target` needs to be a function. `threading.Thread(target=self.classOne.method_one)` is probably right unless `method_one()` returns a function.